# Why am I getting "not implicitly convertible" and "member not found" errors when trying to use TokenTimelock?

Tags: solidity, truffle, tokens, timelock

I am rewriting some code in order to be able to set 4 timelocks from a fixed date to team members. I always get the error

```
~/code/ANCToken$ truffle  compile

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/ANCToken.sol

TypeError: Type contract TokenTimelock is not implicitly convertible to expected type address.
   --> project:/contracts/ANCToken.sol:123:31:
    |
123 |             team[i].fstLock = new TokenTimelock(_IERC20Token, team[i].teamMember, block.timestamp + fifteenDaysInSeconds);
    |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,TypeError: Member "release" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address.
   --> project:/contracts/ANCToken.sol:130:13:
    |
130 |             team[i].fstLock.release();
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.4.26 (core: 5.4.26)
Node v12.22.8
```

And I can't understand the reason... Could you please help me?

```solidity
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/TokenTimelock.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";


contract Ancestry is ERC20, ERC20Burnable, Pausable, Ownable {

    using SafeMath for *;

    // Wallets
    address payable deployerWallet = payable(0xE76dfad0a129CD7B72E3E6aD172F98865998c1aB);// Deployer/Owner wallet
    
    address payable rewardsWallet = payable(0x9f5094675526898e4260a411241d374232021183); // Wallet to collect 5% of each transaction
    address payable preSaleTokens = payable(0xE76dfad0a129CD7B72E3E6aD172F98865998c1aB); // Wallet where Presale Tokens reserve are minted to

    // for excluding addresses from 5% fee
    mapping(address => uint256) private _excludedFromFee;

    // for mapping team wallets to 4 team timelocks each
    struct TeamTimelocks{
        address teamMember;
        address fstLock;
        address sndLock;
        address thrLock;
        address frtLock;
    }

    TeamTimelocks[] team;



    // fechas en unixtimestamp GMT
    
    /*
    17/01/2022 00:00:00 1642377600
    24/01/2022 00:00:00 1642978800
    */

    /*
       p1Date         - Epoch del 17/01/22
       p2Date         - Epoch del 24/01/22
       PublicSaleDate - Epoch del 31/01/22
    */

    /* real times for deploying timestamps
   
    uint256 public constant PublicSaleDate = 1643587200;
    uint256 public constant fifteenDaysInSeconds = 1296000;
    uint256 public constant oneMonthInSeconds = 2592000;
    uint256 public constant oneMonthAndAHalfInSeconds = 3888000;
    uint256 public constant twoMonthsInSeconds = 5184000;
*/
    
    uint256 public  PublicSaleDate = block.timestamp + 120;
    uint256 public  fifteenDaysInSeconds = 140;
    uint256 public  oneMonthInSeconds = 160;
    uint256 public  oneMonthAndAHalfInSeconds = 180;
    uint256 public  twoMonthsInSeconds = 200;

    constructor() ERC20("Ancestry", "ANC") {

        distributeAndLock();
    }

    function pause() public onlyOwner {
        _pause();
    }

    function unpause() public onlyOwner {
        _unpause();
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount)
        internal
        whenNotPaused
        override
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
    }

    // token distribution and timelocks for Team

    function distributeAndLock() internal {

        IERC20 _IERC20Token = IERC20(this);

        // Mint presale available tokens without lock for DXSale
        _mint(preSaleTokens, 2600000 * 10 ** decimals());

        // Mint for rewards Wallet without lock
        _mint(rewardsWallet, 13000000 * 10 ** decimals());

        // Mint Reserve+Airdrop+Marketing tokens without lock
        _mint(rewardsWallet, 3900000 * 10 ** decimals());

        // Team distribution
        // calculates release of tokens by quarters
        uint256 teamTokensTotal        = 3900000 * 10 ** decimals();
        uint256 tokensPerMember        = teamTokensTotal.div(8);
        uint256 quarterTokensPerMember = tokensPerMember.div(4);

        // 1 Add member's wallets to array
        team[0].teamMember = 0xE76dfad0a129CD7B72E3E6aD172F98865998c1aB;
        team[1].teamMember = 0x58d299cf28e508704646A95d78AEA4EFddd6B7c8;
        team[2].teamMember = 0xFe76F9F0aF1F8250CB30767461921e81871d9037;
        team[3].teamMember = 0xEaEEB732b67169F3Bc24DAA6271e95fc104e0FC0;
        team[4].teamMember = 0x631bB0244071aC67663241657c8312eCDb23A665;
        team[5].teamMember = 0xE8DD32180803095A57b4Ff1B475753ea5D1c3b8d;
        team[6].teamMember = 0x3C9E6083E2Db441843c9d6678f1E54cC9bb5B719;
        team[7].teamMember = 0xdDfACfD8B9dA4c15f61beB43B41Db12c33c6898F;

        for(uint i=0; i < team.length; i++) {
            team[i].fstLock = new TokenTimelock(_IERC20Token, team[i].teamMember, block.timestamp + fifteenDaysInSeconds);
            this.mint(team[i].fstLock, quarterTokensPerMember);
        }
    }

    function releaseFirstTL() public {
        for(uint i=0; i < team.length; i++)
            team[i].fstLock.release();
    }

    function releaseSecondTL() public {
        for(uint i=0; i < team.length; i++)
            team[i].sndLock.release();
    }

    function releaseThirdTL() public {
        for(uint i=0; i < team.length; i++)
            team[i].thrLock.release();
    }

    function releaseFourthTL() public {
        for(uint i=0; i < team.length; i++)
            team[i].frtLock.release();
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `fstLock` field is of type `address` but you're using it as if it were a `TokenTimelock` contract.

> ```
> TypeError: Type contract TokenTimelock is not implicitly convertible to expected type address.
>    --> project:/contracts/ANCToken.sol:123:31:
>     |
> 123 |             team[i].fstLock = new TokenTimelock(_IERC20Token, team[i].teamMember, block.timestamp + fifteenDaysInSeconds);
>     |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

`new` returns a contract type and contracts are not implicitly convertible to addresses. You cannot assign one to another without an explicit conversion.

> ```
> TypeError: Member "release" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address.
>    --> project:/contracts/ANCToken.sol:130:13:
>     |
> 130 |             team[i].fstLock.release();
>     |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

The [`release()` function](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/6bd6b76d1156e20e45d1016f355d154141c7e5b9/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/TokenTimelock.sol#L59-L69) is available only on the `TokenTimelock` contract, not on arbitrary `address` variables.